# Xamarin Forms Next key click in keyboard is not working in Droid application

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms application I added the code for enabling Next and Done buttons on the keyboard. But nothing is happening on the next key click. But done key click is working fine. Following is my code sample

Render:

```
public class HACCPEntryRenderer :EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        if (Control != null) {


            if ((Element as MyEntry).IsLastItem)
                Control.ImeOptions = Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done;
            else
                Control.ImeOptions = Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Next;

        }
    }
```

And I added the completed event in the code behind

```
private void Entry_Input_Completed(object sender , EventArgs args)
    {           
        nextEntry.Focus ();
    }
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a hack for this to work, I had to use the messaging center to set the focus of the entry (Android version since iOS was working fine)

Inside the Custom Renderer:

```
Control.ImeOptions = Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Next;
Control.SetImeActionLabel("Next", Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Next);

switch(entry.CustomImeAction){
    case ImeAction.Email:
        editText.EditorAction += (object sender, TextView.EditorActionEventArgs args) =>
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<IEntryMessages>(this, "Email");
        };
        break;
    case ImeAction.Password:
        editText.EditorAction += (object sender, TextView.EditorActionEventArgs args) =>
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<IEntryMessages>(this, "Password");
        };
        break;
}
```

On your entry/page:

```
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IEntryMessages> (this, "Email", (sender) => {
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (async () => {
        await Task.Run( () => Task.Delay( 1 ) );
        PasswordEntry.Focus();
    });
});

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IEntryMessages> (this, "Password", (sender) => {
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (async () => {
        await Task.Run( () => Task.Delay( 1 ) );
        ConfirmPasswordEntry.Focus();
    });
});
```